# How to change .xls to .xlsx filetype on export

Tags: javascript

I am using this codes to export table to excel with the file type (.xls) I want to change it to (.xlsx) Thanks

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.download = "filename.xls";
                    link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                    link.click();
  }
})()
```

Comment: Just change the filename - that is already an XSLX.

Comment: Amadan thanks but when I tried it Microsoft Office Excel cannot open the file.

Comment: Well, what's the difference between the file formats?

Comment: We are encountering some compatibility issues with .xls